# What is wrong with following date representation?

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have two strings which are pointing at the same time:

> "2018-07-18 12:00:09+0000"

AND

> "2018-07-18 15:00:09+0300"

I am receiving them from backend.
The problem is that when I try to parse them I get different date objects:

```
public class Main {

    private static SimpleDateFormat FORMAT;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssX";

        FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN, Locale.US);

        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-07-18 12:00:09+0000"));
        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-07-18 15:00:09+0300"));
    }

    private static Date parseDate(String source) {
        try {
            return FORMAT.parse(source);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Tue Jul 17 19:00:09 EST 2018
Wed Jul 18 07:00:09 EST 2018
```

I am really stuck.

Comment: Your hh should be HH.

Comment: the pattern "hh" stands for 12 hours format, but your date strings seem to be formatted with 24 hours format. You should use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX"`

Comment: Yes what @BoristheSpider said. It's a timezone issue.

Comment: Thomas Kläger and JB Nizet you're damn right! my fault!

Comment: Confirmed, after changing the code it prints Wed Jul 18 15:00:09 EEST 2018 for both

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).